# Adding leading 'zeros' to a number without library in C

Tags: c

I wanted to store 'two zeros' in a value e.g. answer(which is a BYTE) and send it over to RS-485. How can I do that without any library?
Secondly, I tried by adding char '0' to zero(0) but instead it converted it to equivalent of zero which is '48' and send it over RS-485.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUtDd.png)

Thanks,

Comment: Leading zeros are meaningful only when representing the number as text/string. So sounds like you want to send strings, and not numbers.

Comment: I want to send a number basically which has the limit of 1 byte (8 bits)... So it can only send two numbers. What I expect is '00' in the output instead of single '0'.

Comment: Post the code snippet instead of the link to your screenshot.

Comment: I posted the picture but the website didn't allow the permission.

Comment: You should not post a screenshot, copy the text verbatim, please. -- Please [edit] your question additionally, and provide the [mre] of the receiving code. I assume that you are looking there to see what you sent. At least this is what I interpreted from "_What I expect is '00' in the output instead of single '0'._" So we need to know how you come to this output.

Answer (score 0):

```
    sprintf(buffer, sizeof buffer, "%03d", the_byte_number);
```

will do what you want, you can then send the buffer contents over the RS-485 using something like:

```
    write(rs_485_file_descriptor, buffer, strlen(buffer);
```

if you refuse to use even the C standard library, you'll have to do the conversion yourself:

```
char *zero_pad(uint8_t numb, char *buffer)
{
    static char tab[] = "01234567898";
    /* you need to have at least three characters for the three digits in
     * buffer, no check is made here for efficiency reasons.
     * we advance the buffer 3 positions first, and then go backwards,
     * filling with characters, from the least significant digit to the most.
     * in case you want the string to be null terminated, you must start
     * with the '\0' char.
     */
#if YOU_WANT_IT_NULL_TERMINATED
    buffer += 4;
    *--buffer = '\0';
#else
    buffer += 3;
#endif
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        int dig = numb % 10;
        *--buffer = tab[dig];
        number /= 10;
    }
    return buffer;
} /* zero_pad */
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks but whenever I tried to send the char instead of sending the 'char value' it sends the ASCII value. For example I tried to simply send the '0' and add it to zero. Instead of sending the char '0' it sends the equivalent value of 48.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe as *'two zeros'* are two nibbles in the hexadecimal representation of the *BYTE* 0. Of course if you add the ASCII character '0' to zero, you get 48<sub>10</sub>. If you just want to send the *BYTE* `answer`, no conversion is needed.

```
    wr = write(fd, &answer, sizeof answer);
```

Comment: case QUERY_STUNDEN_LSB:
  if(flagForLoop <= anz_ledtreiber)
         {
          char *zeros = utoa_bin(&temp_str, temp_uint16, 2);
          answer = '0';
          //answer = led_treiber[flagForLoop].stunden % 100;
         }
         else{
          flagForLoop = 1;
         }
        if (querynr_gueltig()==0)
          f_dalitx = 1;
        break;
In the code above, I've to send to append 2 zeros, I used the code above but it doesn't work because of the "conversion".

Comment: 1. This _code above_ does not _send_ anything. 2. What results if you try my suggestion? 3. Wherefrom do you know what you shall send? 4. You should cite the documentation of the data format(s).

Comment: "answer" is a type 'BYTE'. I'm sending the data to another device which can only receive a 'byte' (8 bits only). I'm sending data (1000) separately in 2 bytes. In 1 byte I send 10 in another byte I've to send '00'. Now the problem is, only 1 '0' is sent so on the other side (device) it appears '100' instead of '1000'.

Comment: (I wrote my deleted comment when you posted only the first sentence of the above.) I suspect you misinterpret what you send, how this is displayed or what you have to send, because what you describe is impossible - a byte can't consist of only one binary coded decimal. If you don't want to show how you _send_ nor answer question 3 nor point to an information source, I think you can't be helped.

Comment: it's a standard DALI command which is used for the lighting control system. I want to send the hours from DALI Slave to Dali Master. Dali slave can only send a byte to DALI master. So we can only send a single BYTE.

Comment: Which byte value in which number system do you send where you say _I send 10_, and which byte value in which number system did you send where you say _only 1 '0' is sent_?

Comment: Hi, Thanks! I called the manufacturer today and he told me that's the interface of the App. Thank you for your help. :)